# How to suppress snprintf() warning 'directive writing up to xx bytes...'

Tags: c++, string, compiler-warnings

I'm using `snprintf()` to write string into a buffer.

```
#define MAXLEN 256
char line[MAXLEN];
char buf[MAXLEN];

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Hi%s", line);
```

When compiling, it shows warning

```
directive writing up to 256 bytes into a region of size 254
```

Any better way to solve this? I don't want to use `malloc(...)` or similar dynamic allocating function.

Comment: `Any better way to solve this?` _How_ do you want to solve it? In the case `line` is a string of 255 characters, do you want to print only 253 of them?

Comment: @KamilCuk Or how should I modify it?  e.g. Allocating small 'char line' is better?

Comment: Making sizeof(buf) larger or sizeof(line) smaller would do it, I think.

Comment: The compiler is warning you that the number of elements in `line` is too big for the output buffer. Of course, the size of `line` doesn't tell you how many characters are actually in it; that's determined by where the terminating nul is. That's determined by the length of the string, which the compiler has no way of knowing. In short: that warning is nonsense. You can either work around that nanny warning or turn it off.

Comment: I'm asking what the result you _want_ to have? In case `line` is a long string of 255 characters, what do you _want_ to happen then? Should `buf` be `Hi<253 characters from line>`? Or do you want `buf` to be `Hi<all of the line content>`? If the first, silence the warning, if the second, increase buf size.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the second result.

Then you have to make sure the destination buffer is long enough to hold it. For example:

```
char line[MAXLEN];
char buf[MAXLEN + 2];
```

that way `buf` can hold a whole `line` and also two `"Hi"` characters.

Comment: snprintf is a function that always makes a null terminated string. If the source is larger than destionation, and you provide the length of the destination, snprintf will fill in the destination only to the defined size, and will make sure it will be null terminated. I understand that warning for sprintf, but not for snprint.